# How to import members spreadsheet

Tags: civimember, import

I'm new to CiviCRM and have a somewhat noob question about importing membership data from a spreadsheet.
We have this data in a way that each row is a company with organizational data (membership type and date and tax number..etc) and some of the columns in this row have also individuals (employees of the company) in them with their contact details in other columns.
How should we start the importing is my question. Should I first import our members as organizations and then do another import for the individuals...all into contacts? How to connect these to the companies? Does it work with say based on ID-s that I give to the companies beforehand?
Also how to import these same companies to the membership module?

I'm using latest Joomla and CiviCRM.

Comment: I am so new I didn't spend enough time reading this:-) https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19056/noob-query-importing-contacts-and-membership.

Comment: if that is enough of an answer we can either mark this as a duplicate question, or we (you) could add that link as your own answer

Answer (score 2):

This has been answered before indeed: [noob query : Importing contacts and membership](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19056/noob-query-importing-contacts-and-membership)
and here: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/membership/manual-entry-of-memberships/
Thanks for the exchange:-)